# Ruby - function changes hash but not integer variable

Tags: ruby, proc, lexical-scope

I have a function that takes in some parameters including a hash and an integer variable and adjusts their value. The function alters the value of the hash to be used again, however the integer variable resets itself. I believe it's because it's altering a copy of that variable, but I wanted to know how I can change it fully. I've been reading things about proc's but unfortunately I can't seem to solve my issue.

My code is below:

```
def buyProducts(product, amount, balance, foods, myProducts)
    totalPrice = foods[product] * amount
    balance -= totalPrice
    myProducts[product] = amount

    puts "You bought some #{product}\n"
    puts "Your remaining balance is $#{balance}\n"
    puts "Your current inventory is #{myProducts}"
end
```

Here, myProducts is a hash which updates each time. balance however is not, thats set as 100 from the start. while the line "your remaining balance" does update, when the function is called again it resets to 100.

I appreciate this is a simple question but any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: What you are asking is not possible. Ruby is pass-by-value, it is not possible to change the binding of a variable in the caller's scope. There is no pass-by-reference in Ruby. I suspect that this is an [X-Y-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/2988) and you are not *actually* looking for pass-by-reference.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic for `buyProducts` to be a method on a "shopping cart" object of some sort, then `myProducts` and `totalPrice` would be instance variables and `balance` would be an instance variable in another "account" or "credit card" object. The result would look more like Ruby, make your problem go away, and you wouldn't have a method with five positional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the key difference: you **reassign** [the local variable] `balance`, but not `myProducts`. Instead, you simply **change state** of myProducts. That's why these changes "survive" across invocations of the method: the object is the same, it just holds different content.

This is not possible with integers, because each integer is its own object and doesn't have any mutable state.

Your method will have to communicate the changes to the external state by, for example, returning new value of `balance` (it will then be the caller's responsibility to track/apply the new value). Or you could set an instance variable.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I've returned the value of balance and then changed my formula later to alter the variable which seems to be working. Thank you for your explanation!